# Reverse log like tail

Tags: php, logging, reverse

I would like to reverse my system log.

My system log looks like this:

```
[ 2016-03-17T15:52:00+08:00 ] 0.0.0.0 /Pwebshell/index.php/Log/GetLog
INFO: [ route_check ] --START--
INFO: CheckRoute Behavior ::run [ RunTime:0.001000s ]
INFO: [ route_check ] --END-- [ RunTime:0.001000s ]
INFO: [ app_begin ] --START--
INFO: ReadHtmlCache Behavior ::run [ RunTime:0.001000s ]
INFO: [ app_begin ] --END-- [ RunTime:0.001000s ]

[ 2016-03-17T15:52:16+08:00 ] 0.0.0.0 /Pwebshell/index.php/Log/GetLog
INFO: [ route_check ] --START--
INFO: CheckRoute Behavior ::run [ RunTime:0.000000s ]
INFO: [ route_check ] --END-- [ RunTime:0.001000s ]
INFO: [ app_begin ] --START--
INFO: ReadHtmlCache Behavior ::run [ RunTime:0.000000s ]
INFO: [ app_begin ] --END-- [ RunTime:0.000000s ]
```

I would like to print it like this:

```
[ 2016-03-17T15:52:16+08:00 ] 0.0.0.0 /Pwebshell/index.php/Log/GetLog
INFO: [ route_check ] --START--
INFO: CheckRoute Behavior ::run [ RunTime:0.000000s ]
INFO: [ route_check ] --END-- [ RunTime:0.001000s ]
INFO: [ app_begin ] --START--
INFO: ReadHtmlCache Behavior ::run [ RunTime:0.000000s ]
INFO: [ app_begin ] --END-- [ RunTime:0.000000s ]

[ 2016-03-17T15:52:00+08:00 ] 0.0.0.0 /Pwebshell/index.php/Log/GetLog
INFO: [ route_check ] --START--
INFO: CheckRoute Behavior ::run [ RunTime:0.001000s ]
INFO: [ route_check ] --END-- [ RunTime:0.001000s ]
INFO: [ app_begin ] --START--
INFO: ReadHtmlCache Behavior ::run [ RunTime:0.001000s ]
INFO: [ app_begin ] --END-- [ RunTime:0.001000s ]
```

What I have tried so far:

1 First of all I read the log using `file_get_contents`

```
$content = file_get_contents('log');
```

2 Then I used a regular expression to select the entries.

```
preg_match_all('#(\[\s+\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}.*\].*?)\[\s+\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}#s', $content, $matches);
```

3 I will use `array_reverse` to reverse the log.

But the `$matches` were not selected correctly by the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three separate issues with the regular expression:

- You'd need the first `.*` to be ungreedy otherwise it will match up to the final `]` in the file.
- Your regular expression won't match the final entry because it isn't followed by another entry.
- Each match "captures" the text matched, including the following `\[\s+\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}` (ie it captures the start of the next entry). This means only some of the matches will be returned. To correct this, we need to convert the final part into a lookahead assertion using `(?=...)`.

Something like the following should fix these three problems.

```
preg_match_all('#(\[\s+\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}.*?\].*?)(?=\[\s+\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}|$)#s', $content, $matches);
```

However your entries appear to be separated by double line feeds. Why not just split the log on these? Assuming you don't get double line feeds naturally in the log data, this would be easier to read, faster, and less error prone.

The following would work on Linux:

```
$lines = explode("\n\n", $content);
$lines = array_reverse($lines);
echo implode("\n\n", $lines);
```

On Windows you might need to replace `\n\n` with `\r\n\r\n`.

An improved solution which would work regardless of the type of line feeds, allow for white space between the line feeds, and output using your system's default end of line might look like:

```
$lines = preg_split("#\r?\n\s*\n#", $content);
$lines = array_reverse($lines);
echo implode(PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $lines);
```

This will also handle the fact that your log content appears to sometimes contain more than two line feeds separating entries.

Comment: 1 problem  i use `preg_match_all('#(\[\s+\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}.*?\].*?)(\[\s+\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}|$)#s'` ,but i can got the last  log ,i think it maybe not end of '$',

Comment: i use `$lines = explode("\n\n", $content);
$lines = array_reverse($lines);
echo implode("\n\n", $lines); it cant get the result i will.

Comment: The `$` matches the end of the string, not a literal dollar sign. However I've realised there's another fault in the regex. I'll edit the answer to fix it.

Comment: i do not know what is delimiter in the $content, so i cant use explode,can you tell me ,how to print all character include "\n \t " and so on ,

Comment: Perhaps you are using (or the file was generated on) Windows? You could try replacing `\n\n` with `\r\n\r\n`. I'll edit the answer to use a regex to match all possible line endings including if there's whitespace in between the lines.

Comment: You can see which characters are used for delimiters with `echo addcslashes($content, "\r\n\t");`, but the third solution in the answer should work regardless of line endings.

Comment: i used  var_dump(addcslashes($content, "\r\n\t"));the result is : `string '[ 2016-03-17T15:51:55+08:00 ] 0.0.0.0 /Pwebshell/index.php/Index/index.html\r\nINFO: [ route_check ] --START--\r\nINFO: CheckRoute Behavior ::run [ RunTime:0.001000s ]\r\n` ,i got the delimiters , thank you